# How to write BETWEEN query in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a problem and I want to know whether this is the right way to write a BETWEEN query in yii2.

In my controller code i have declared `$to_price` and here is my SearchModel code,but i always get the value as `null` for `$this->to_price` ,following is my  `search model` code

```
 public function search($params) {
    $query = Events::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->joinWith(['eventsImages']);

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'main_category_id' => $this->main_category_id,
        'address' => $this->address,
    ]);



    //$to_price = $params->to_price;
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description])

        ->andFilterWhere(['between', 'price', $this ->price, $this -> to_price])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'image', $this->image]);

    $command = $query->createCommand();// Created $command works fine in mysql


    return $dataProvider; //But in $dataProvider it doesnt return any result
}
```

If it is than i am not getting any results back but i can see that the command which is generated works perfect in `mysql`

So whats wrong here???

Comment: make sure your search model has `attribute1` and `attribute2` and must have rules config to massively assign... ..provide code of your searchModel...  between query is implemented rightly...

Comment: @DoubleH i have added the code but in deubugger i found that the query is fine and `$this->to_price` also gets the price and query works in `mysql` when i fire it manually but it doesnt return any result via `dataprovider`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your command works? The SQL code may be correct, but the parameters you bind to the command may be wrong. In other words, can you `var_dump` both `$this->price` and `$this->to_price` right before you create `$command`?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in spaces $this ->to_price and $this ->price. 
It should be $this->to_price and $this->price.
So change between filter line code

```
->andFilterWhere(['between', 'price', $this ->price, $this -> to_price])
```

To

```
->andFilterWhere(['between', 'price', $this->price, $this->to_price])
```

Spaces are not allowed after $this and -> operator